How to access a git private repo that's affiliated with org user
I have a perosnal github account that is used in my global gitconfig, and I need to push versions to my organization's private repo, that is accessed with a DIFFERENNT org github user,
How do I use my org github credentials in the designated folder locally, without changing my global gitconfig?
I've tried to create a git-creds file locally and apply it to the local repo, but the
git push

command was failed and I got: 'repository https://github.com/org-name/repo-name.git not found'.
Moreover, I've waited for a git-credentials-manager prompt somewhere, but didn't get any (I have it installed).
PS: I am using macos
Thanks!
